# How far apart are the bases in non-major league games?

Tags: baseball

I was recently at a single-A baseball game, and I'm not a great judge of distance, but I wasn't sure that the bases were a whole 90 feet apart.

How far apart are the bases in the minor leagues, and also Little League?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Official Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2014/official_baseball_rules.pdf) of Major League Baseball state that base paths are 90 feet long.  In addition, the Official Rules state the following:

> This code of rules governs the playing of baseball games by professional teams of Major League Baseball and the leagues that are members of the National Association of Professional Baseball Leagues.

The [National Association of Professional Baseball Leagues](http://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/National_Association_of_Professional_Baseball_Leagues) is the umbrella organization for the minor leagues, and in 1999 the organization changed its name to Minor League Baseball.  Since Minor League Baseball is governed by the same rules as Major League Baseball, the minor leagues have 90 foot base paths.

In Little League baseball, the [length of the base paths](http://www.littleleague.org/leagueofficers/fieldspecs.htm) varies depending on the age of the players and local preferences:

> Generally, the distance between base paths on fields for 12-year-olds and below in baseball and in all divisions of softball is 60 feet. A local Little League board of directors may opt to use a 50-foot diamond in the Tee Ball divisions. The distance in all divisions of baseball for 13-year-olds,    is up to 90 feet, with a local league option to shorten the distance to 75 feet for Junior League Baseball and 70 feet for Intermediate (50/70) Baseball Division for regular season play.